# applet always giving warning dialog box

Tags: java, applet, self-signed, signed-applet

In my application we are using **self signed applet**,

previously we were getting dialog with one check box to remember choice.
but now a day after updating Java version to 7u40 we are not getting this option,
thats why it every time asking for accepting risk.

any idea regarding this how to avoid such dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Java 7u40 [release note](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u40-relnotes-2004172.html).
Java removed feature of “**Remember this decision**” for self-signed and unsigned applets.

**New Security Warnings for Unsigned and Self-Signed Applications**

> New warnings are added in the dialogs for Unsigned and Self-Signed applications. From the dialogs for Unsigned and Self-Signed applets, "Remember this decision"  option has been removed. In addition, the previously remembered decisions for self-signed and unsigned applets will be ignored.

For more information, see [Security Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/securityDialogs.html)

The only option to get rid of warning dialog is to get your applet signed.